# Second screen - how to avoid a mess and offscreen windows (Windows 10)

Tags: windows-10, display, multiple-monitors, external-display, desktop-customization

I have successfully set up a TV as second screen (HDMI) - mainly to watch YouTube on. Selected 'Desktop extended mode', so I can move the YouTube/Twitch windows over there. Even full-screen works fine. Great.

A very nasty problem remains, however:

- When switching users or resuming from sleep mode, the **positions of browser windows on the main screen get messed up**. To the point where they are no longer accessible. It looks as though they are on a third non-existent screen right of the main. The TV is on the left.

How do I avoid this mess? 
And if not, how can I at least get back the browser window to the main screen.

The strange 3rd display also appears when I click "Detect". See picture. I have not connected anything else. [image]

Comment: It's a strange world. Since I have explicitly activated the 3rd display, which is VGA, I am unable to reproduce the problem. It now shows as "3", but actually it is not there.

Comment: Now the windows are at least not hidden after hibernation, but still resized to (I guess) the default size of display 3. What a horrible mess.

Answer (score 0):

I use paid software to avoid this problem, namely Actual Tools Window Manager.

But that said, you can simply undo the problem by first selecting the program in the taskbar so it is activated, then hold WIN+SHIFT+LEFT/RIGHT arrow to move it from screen to screen until it is on your main display.

If for some reason that doesn't work, then use the following trick to snap any window to your mouse cursor.

Hover the icon in your taskbar until you see the preview window popup. Hover the preview window and right-click it. Click Move to make the window go into move mode. This mode will be greyed out if the window is minimized or maximised. If so, click restore first, then repeat the steps and select move.

In move mode, moving your mouse cursor will do nothing. But if you press an arrow key, you actually move the window one pixel into the direction you were moving, but even better, moving the mouse now will snap the window onto the mouse cursor, bringing it instantly to the screen your mouse cursor is on. To release, click once with the left mouse button.

It can happen that your window spawns in a minimized state offscreen, this trick will bring you the window back, but the window will be a small block. Simply drag the edges to make it bigger again.

Comment: Thx for the Win+Shift+L/R shortcuts, did not know those. Paid software for a trivial thing... no way ;-)

Comment: @DoctorNuu I have a feeling you are a user like me and want to control a lot of aspects. I would like to advise you to look at the software, because it can do so much more and it is not that expensive either. The software will run in full function for 30 days before you need a license, and if you get a license but it expires, the software will keep running indefinitely, you just cannot update to a newer version without going back into demo mode. Also, they have cheaper functions that only offer a subset of what the main program can do. I'ts worth a look for a power user.

Comment: Microsoft probably does not care about the bug, because Windows 10 is free